# Decoding Json data from API

Tags: c#, json, api

I am new to Json and have to deserialize some Json data received from a url.
I am using an API provided for me to log a user into an application.

### The API:

Logging in

To login, make the following call

```
<site>/Users/login/username:<email>/password:<password>.json
```

• Success Response

```
{
  “response”:{
       “sessionId” : “<sessionId>”,
       “businesses” : [{
          “<bizId-1>” : “<bizName-1>”,
          “<bizId-2>” : “<bizName-2>” ,
          “<bizId-n>” : “<bizName-n>”
       }]
  },
  “messages” :{"msgs":"","errs":""}
}
```

An example of an actual response is as below.

```
{
  "response":{
     "sessionId":"50b702d8-78dc-4d65-9de8-2510c327a7be",
     "businesses":[
        {"50c657af0ad8-4ce7-bb08-1d60c327a7be":"All of The Lights"},
        {"50cf705a-ded4-4c7d-95df-51c8c327a7be":"Tomatoes Inc"},
        {"50d2cf88-e664-4103-99f9-1aa0c327a7be":"Joe's Jalepinos"},
        {"50d2d9b9-c358-4129-b9ec-1aa0c327a7be":"Pizza Place"},
        {"50eed93e-f49c-4dff-8c7a-33f0c327a7be":"Samsung"},
        {"51036f10-e9c0-47ecb73d-0f50c327a7be":"Peppers"},
        {"51036fcd-a6b8-4103-8e160f82c327a7be":"Puppy"}
    ]
   },
   "messages":{"msgs":"","errs":""}
}
```

I have the following code:

```
try
{
   serverUrl = "https://eko-app.com/Users/login/username:" + usernameEntered + "/password:" + passwordEntered + ".json";

   var w = new WebClient();
   var jsonData = string.Empty;

   // make the login api call
   jsonData = w.DownloadString(serverUrl);

   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
   {
      var dataResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);
      // need help here
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I first want to retrieve the session Id from the response. If it exists, then a user is allowed to login, if the session id is null then login is rejected. How do I do this?

Also, once a user is logged in, I would like to create a list showing the number of businesses per user and their respective business Ids.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it in a strongly typed way create a class that mirrors the Json you want to deserialise (only the properties you are interested in are necessary).

```
class LoginResponseDetails
{
    public string SessionId {get;set;} // this might be better as a GUID

    public Hashtable Businesses {get;set;} // this could be Dictionary<string, string> or Dictionary<Guid, string>

    // other properties here...
}

class LoginResponse
{
    LoginResponseDetails Response {get;set;}
    // other properties here...
}
```

Then deserialise to this class:

```
var response = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(jsonData);
var sessionId = response.Response.SessionId;
```

etc...

Comment: Thanks for your reply user2965995. I am just having a problem on how to read the Business array/list separately. I.e to get the business ID and Business Name for each line.

Comment: I've edited my answer, try using either a Hashtable, Dictionary<string, string> or Dictionary<Guid, string>

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, simply need to look at the properties of the anonymous type.

Try something like

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
{
  var dataResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonData);

  if (dataResult != null && dataResult.response.sessionId != null)
  {
     // logged in
     // iterate and show bussiness list
  } else {
     Console.WriteLine("Login failed");
  }
}
```

See the JSON.NET docs - http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/DeserializeAnonymousType.htm

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kami. I am just having a problem on how to read the Business array/list separately. I.e to get the business ID and Business Name for each line.